# Jquery datatables not working after row deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table on which I have to perform filtering. I am using datatables jquery plugin. I have to delete all rows from datatables when user selects a particular option from dropdown and I have to fill the table with new data. I am doing it like this.

`$("#results tbody").remove();` //remove the tbody element from table

`mySelect.append('<tbody>');` //now append tbody along with rows

`mySelect.append('<tr><td > '+issueKey+' </td> <td><a href= ' + link + ' >  '+summary+' </td><td> '+ days+' </td></tr>');` //this operation is repeated

```
mySelect.append('</tbody>');
```

After adding this into the table I am calling

```
dataTable.fnReloadAjax();
```

But the table is not refreshing and search, sort is not working. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. :)

I still don't know why the above one is not working but the following code is working now. Can  anyone explain why the above code is not working.

`dataTable.fnClearTable();` //clear the table

`dataTable.fnAddData( [issueKey, "<a href=" + link + " >" + summary+ "</a>" , days]);`  // add data. inbuilt function in dataTables

`dataTable.fnDraw();` // redraw the table